# Unable to access a mongodb model from client through graphql

Tags: mongodb, graphql

The backend mutation syntax which is accessing mongodb.

```
const graphql = require("graphql");
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLList,
} = graphql;


const UserType = require("./TypeDefs/UserType");
const RemoveUserType = require("./TypeDefs/RemoveUserType");
const  Users = require('../../mongodb/models/users')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema


const graphql = require("graphql");
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLList,
} = graphql;


const UserType = require("./TypeDefs/UserType");
const RemoveUserType = require("./TypeDefs/RemoveUserType");
const  Users = require('../../mongodb/models/users')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema



const fetchAllUsers = async () =>{
  let users = await Users.find({})
  console.log(users)
        return users;
}


const createANewUser = async (args) =>{
console.log(args)
const newUser = await Users.create({
firstname:args.firstname,
lastname:args.lastname,
email:args.email,
password:args.password,
   })
    await newUser.save()
    console.log(newUser)
    return newUser
}
const deleteAUser = async (args)=>{
 console.log(args._id)
const deletedUser = await Users.findByIdAndDelete(args._id)
  return deletedUser
}

const RootQuery = new   GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQueryType",
  fields: {
    getAllUsers: {
      type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
      args: { id: { type: GraphQLInt } },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        let usersData = fetchAllUsers()
        return usersData
      },
    },
  },
});

const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Mutation",
  fields: {
    createUser: {
      type: UserType,
      args: {
        firstname: { type: GraphQLString },
        lastname: { type: GraphQLString },
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString },
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        // userData.push({
        //   id: userData.length + 1,
        //   firstName: args.firstName,
        //   lastName: args.lastName,
        //   email: args.email,
        //   password: args.password ,
        // });
        // return args;
        const newUserData = createANewUser(args);
        return newUserData

      },
    },
    removeUser: {
      type: RemoveUserType,
      args: {
        _id: { type: GraphQLID },
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString },
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        let deletedUserData = deleteAUser(args);
        return deletedUserData;
      },
    }

  },
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({ query: RootQuery, mutation: Mutation });
```

That's the mutation schema for client side

```
export const REMOVE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
mutation removeUser( $id: ID!, $email: String!, $password: String! ) {
  removeUser(_id: $id, email: $email, password: $password) {
    _id
  }
}`;
```

The farm which uses the removeUser function to access the mongo db from client side through graph query language:

```
"use client"

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { REMOVE_USER_MUTATION } from "../GraphQL/Mutations";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";


const FormForDeleteUsers = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [removeUser, { error }] = useMutation(REMOVE_USER_MUTATION);

  
   
 
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col border border-black py-7">
      <input className="py-5 px-12 rounded-sm outline-lime-400  mb-3 border-black border"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Email"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setEmail(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
       <input className="py-5 px-12 rounded-sm outline-lime-400 mb-3  border-black border"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Password"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setPassword(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
       <input className="py-5 px-12 rounded-sm outline-lime-400  border-black border"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Id"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setId(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
       <button onClick={() => {
        console.log(id)
        try{
          console.log(id)
          console.log(email)
          console.log(password)
          console.log(typeof(id))
          console.log(typeof(email)) 
          console.log(typeof(password))     

            removeUser({variables:{_id:"659f42fd8cc72919a0b9e0f2", email:"hari@gmail.com", password:"haripass"}})
        }
        catch(e){
          console.log(error)
        }
       }} className="mt-5 py-5 px-16 bg-green-500 rounded-md hover:bg-lime-500"> Remove User</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FormForDeleteUsers
```

When I check the graphql server with graphiql, it works fine .But when I come from the client it creates a problem .It shows Response not successful `ApolloError:Received status code of 400.` I think it's the problem in that graphql mutation schema which is on client side. But I couldn't figure it out. Hope anyone helps me out. Thanks in advance.